# How to add policy to AWS SAM file to put value in secrets manager with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

```yaml
Policies:
        - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess
        - AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy:
            SecretArn: !Sub 
        - AWSSecretsManagerRotationPolicy:
            SecretArn: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:/${EnvironmentTagName}/*
            Effect: Allow
            FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-****
            Action:
              - secretsmanager:UpdateSecret
              - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
              - secretsmanager:PutSecretValue
            Resource:
```

I want to change secrets value by lambda , but I got this error:-

> AccessDeniedException: User:
> arn:aws:sts::****:assumed-role***/LambdaName is not authorized to
> perform: secretsmanager:PutSecretValue on resource: /***/API_TOKEN
> because no identity-based policy allows the
> secretsmanager:PutSecretValue action

Comment: exactly , I should add it to sam file , and I don't know how fix it

Comment: `AWSSecretsManagerRotationPolicy` policy template has already `secretsmanager:PutSecretValue` action allowed. Can you once just use this policy for your lambda function?
`MyFunction:
  Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ${codeuri}
    Handler: hello.handler
    Runtime: python2.7
    Policies:
      - AWSSecretsManagerRotationPolicy: {}`

Comment: The function syntax is correct I only post policy section of lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to specify policies for a Lambda function in the AWS SAM template:-

1. AWS managed policy named
2. AWS SAM policy template
3. Inline policy document defined

`AWSSecretsManagerRotationPolicy` is AWS SAM Policy template that already includes `secretsmanager:DescribeSecret`, `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue`, **`secretsmanager:PutSecretValue`**, `secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage`, so you don't need to explicitly specify these actions, you can simply use the policy template directly:-

```yaml
MyFunction:
  Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ${codeuri}
    Handler: hello.handler
    Runtime: python2.7
    Policies:
      - AWSSecretsManagerRotationPolicy: # AWS SAM Policy template
          SecretArn: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:your_secret_value"
```

In case you need to specify the policies(**inline**) explicitly for the Lambda function, you can do like so:-

```yaml
Policies:
    - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess # AWS Managed Policy
    - Version: '2012-10-17' # Inline Policy Document
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - secretsmanager:UpdateSecret
            - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
            - secretsmanager:PutSecretValue
          Resource: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:your_secret_value"
```

Useful Resources:-

- [AWS Repost - How do I grant IAM permissions to a Lambda function
  using an AWS SAM template?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-sam-template-permissions)
- [AWS SAM policy templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-templates.html)
- [Policy template list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html)

Comment: worked, Thank you :)
the policy inline fix the problem

Comment: thank you , just one thing the `AWSSecretsManagerRotationPolicy` need FuntionName I add nothing happened , but inline policy worked , good job

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, why `AWSSecretsManagerRotationPolicy` need `FunctionName`. With `FunctionName` you can name the lambda function. If you don't specify a name, a unique name is generated for you. It is nothing to do with the policy.